# TextFields are not showing in storyboard?

Tags: swift, storyboard

Hi I am newbie for developing the ios application. I had faced issue I am not able to see the UItextFields in storyboard. But while build the project and run into ios devices its working fine. In IOS mobile it visible all textFields.please find the below given screen shots.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is Sky Floating Label Text Field? Apparently, this component doesn't support rendering to the Interface Builder. It should be @IBDesignable class. Try to use normal UITextField and you will see it in Storyboard.

Comment: But while drag and drop the textFields its working fine, it's able to visible in interface builder.